# JavaScript/Jquery Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, axios, request

I apologize if I word this question wrong, I am very new to JS especially involving node.  But I do have an issue, so in my code, I defined an array outside of any function, literally the first line of the code with no tabs.  When I use `playerlist.push(x)` inside of a function and try to do `console.log(playerlist[0])`(the array is empty so I know there will only be 1 item in the array) it logs as undefined.  The array in question is playerlist.  The console.log call that is not working is the second to last line of code.

```
const playerlist = []
const playerdict = {}
const mtl = []
const queryString = window.location.search;
const evpath1 = queryString.split('?')[1] + '?' + queryString.split('?')[2];
const evpath2 = queryString.replace('?window=', '/').split('?')[1];
var uri = 'https://fortnitetracker.com/events/' + evpath2 + '/watch';
var data = {};
data.uri = uri
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/',
    data : data,
    success: function(data){
        metaEventId(data);  
    }
});

function metaEventId(data){
    var metaEventId = data.split('metaEventId: ')[1].split(',')[0];
    mtl.push(metaEventId)
}

function addplayer() {
    var epicName = $('#epic');
    var uri = 'https://fortnitetracker.com/api/v0/profiles/find?platformUserHandle='
    var data = {};
    data.uri = uri + epicName.val().replace(' ', '+');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : data,
        success: function(data){
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            displayData(data);  
        }
    });
    function displayData(data){
        var epicUserId = data.platformUserId;
        var epicUserName = data.platformUserHandle;
        playerlist.push(epicUserName);
        playerdict[epicUserName] = epicUserId;
        var data = {};
    }
    console.log(playerlist[0]);
}
```

Here is the node side stuff(I belive)

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var request = require('request');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));


app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/static/index.html'));
});

// TRN-Api-Key: 3a586c4e-57f6-4695-8167-c1ea9467fc84
app.post('/',function(req,res){
    request.get(req.body.uri,{
        headers : {
            'TRN-Api-Key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        }},function(error,response,body){
            console.log(body);
            res.json(body);
        });
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port)
```

Comment: How exactly is that running in Node? Normally there's not a `window` object; are you using some kind of DOM library? Or is the code you posted actually browser-side code?

Comment: why not move the console.log after the push?

Comment: Im not 100% sure, I followed a video tutorial on how to setup node, there is another JS file that handles the node stuff I belive, I can post it if you need it.(going to post it anyways)

Comment: You should probably redact that API key.

Comment: These two questions should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321.

Answer (score 0):

Your console log is executing before the items are added to the array. Add the console log in the ajax success function or in the displayData function after the push.

Comment: Right, I tried that and it did work, but I was really hoping to be able to call the variable in another function, is that possible?